# How do I reuse a "react-select" component across my application

Tags: reactjs

I built a reusable multi-select dropdown component with react-select and I want to reuse it across my app, and capture the values on select change

here is the component in `MultiSelect.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactSelect from "react-select";

class MultiSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOptions: {},
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOptions: e });
  };

  render() {
    const student = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("student"));

    return (
      <div className="multi-select">
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <ReactSelect
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          isMulti
          options={student.coursesBag}
          getOptionValue={(option) => option.courseCode}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.courseName}
          closeMenuOnSelect={false}
          hideSelectedOptions={true}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          isOptionDisabled={() => this.state.selectedOptions.length >= 7}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MultiSelect;
```

and here is the instance in `Register.js` where I want to use it and capture the selected options to a `subjects` array:

```
<div className="flex-item">
    <MultiSelect
         label={"Subjects Registered For"}
         placeholder={"Select all that apply..."}
    />
</div>
```

I want to get the selected options and store them in `subjects` using this line

```
const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState({})
```

I am new to react, please let me know if I am doing anything wrong with what I've provided

Comment: What you need is to manage the state from the parent component. Here you are more info about the controlled components: https://www.altogic.com/blog/difference-between-controlled-and-uncontrolled-component#:~:text=%E2%80%8B,the%20state%20of%20the%20component.

Comment: @Klian I thought I was doing that with ```this.state = { selectedOption: [] }``` and the onChange handler ```handleChange```, as the article suggests. Is the any other way to that, that I don't know of?

Comment: No @Kwanele_dev you are setting the state only in MultiSelect but the parent component, Register, doesn't know anything about it. Consider to pass a onClick prop to MultiSelect from Register. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dust-zxzhlr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Klian thanks for your assistance. i have tried to make a ew changes with your recommended articles and added ``` onChange={this.props.onChange}``` as a prop and handle the change event inside ```register.js``` and it works for now. I wouldn't know if that is the best programming practice but I'm open to recommend